# Program based on shared memory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ipc

I am executing the code as given below for the shared memory, but now if i have to give the number of strings and string pattern from the command line, what should i do?? and sebsequently also i have to read the strings and string patterns from shared memory region.

Also if i have to reverse the strings and stored at the same location for that what should i do??

Please help me on this problem.

#define SHMSIZE 500                     /*Shared Memory Size given by us */

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int shmid;
key_t key;
char *shm;



key = 5876;

shmid = shmget(key,SHMSIZE,IPC_CREAT| 0666);            /*Creating Shared Memory */    

if(shmid < 0)
{
perror("shmget");
  exit(1);
}

shm = shmat(shmid,NULL,0);                          /* Shared Memory Attachment */
if(shm == (char *) -1)
{
perror("shmat");
exit(1);
}

printf("Memory attached at %X\n",(int) shm);          /* Printing the address where     Memory is attached */

sprintf(shm,"God is Great");                          /* Write a string to the shared memory */

shmdt(shm);                                           /* Deattach the shared memory segment  */

shm = shmat(shmid,(void *) 0x50000000,0);             /*Reattach the shared memory segment */

printf("Memory Reattached at %X\n",(int) shm);

printf("%s\n",shm);                                   /* Print the desired string */

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In according to take input from user, you need to parse what passed through argv. Then copy the values into your code and write it over the shared memory region. From your code you can do the following:

```
 sprintf(shm, argv[1]);
```

to parse the first parameter passed to your shared memory region. And to reverse the string, copy the string from shared memory into a variable, then reverse it and finally, write it into that shared memory region from your client code. Since, you've created shm with 666 permission this should allow client to write on that portion.

Take a look at here in case you need to understand the concept properly ( http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html)